# Caching of renderBinary responses

Tags: playframework

I am trying to customize serving of some static resources with renderBinary(). 
I would like to serve these assets through controller which optionaly checks 
authorization and serves appropriate file. 
I would also like to cache some file for 1 year as they never change.

The method in my controller looks something like this:

```
    public static void item(String item) { 
             // check authorization ... 
             response.cacheFor("365d"); 
             renderBinary(Play.getFile("static/" + item)); 
    }
```

The problem I am having is that play automatically adds Etag and 
caches it for 1 hour when using renderBinary, so the net effect is that
firefox re-issues request for these files again when needed, only to get 
304 response from play server.

I know I can achieve thing with nginx as frontend but would like to do it
using only play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Play, see https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/772-overwritten-of-cache-control-header-when-apply-renderbinary-to-a-file

Comment: I recently discovered the same bug report, and found a workaround by returning FileInputStream instead of file..

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid the 304 answer, as the cache in Play is a server cache and teh browser has to check the server for details (answer 304 or the item). That's showing the cache works fine, as it's cached and not retrieved again. Keep in mind, though, that cache may miss (if the item is old and removed by cache policy) and then the request would load the item again.

The only real solution is to change the etags to 1 year. There is a property in application.conf, *http.cacheControl*, that can set the time for cache. Default is 1 hour, set it to 1 year, but be aware this will apply to all items (so if you change a javascript file, for example, better change the name too!)

Comment: Hi Pere. You can avoid 304, at least, by setting Last-Modified and Expires headers, but there doesn't seem to be good support in play for this. 
Many sites claim that max-age should do the same, but my firefox seems to ignore it and re-issues the request...

Anyway, it seems i will have to customize plays source or maybe try to make a module for configuring caching...

Comment: @user744959 yes, I meant that if you are relying in server cache (your response.cacheFor) the 304 will be there, as you are creating a server cache, nto forcing the browser to store it. The way you want is (in theory) what I say in the second paragraph, try setting http.cacheControl property to extend the ETag life.

Comment: ok. i thought cacheFor just sets the browser headers, as it seems that play ignores the headers i set in controller. I can get around it by using nginx frontend but is just seems overy complicated for such a simple need...